# Working on SQL Queries in C#

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a better way of implementing multiple SQL queries? I had tried this; it works fine, but I think it's not efficient.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id is:"+dr[0]+" Name is:"+ dr[1]);
    }

    con.Close();

    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
    con2.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Name from Student", con2);
    con2.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2;
    dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr2.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is :"+ dr2[0]);
    }

    con2.Close();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Why not just fetch your data into a DataTable and query the datatable?

Comment: Selecting an entire table is never really going to be efficient unless it's a really small table. Also, the second query is unnecessary, the names would have came down with the first.

Comment: why would you query twice, everything is there at the first query. it is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a Better way of implementing multiple Queries.

1. Re-use the connection string

   ```
   string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
   ```
2. use `using` on connections, commands, and readers:

   ```
   using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", con))
       {
           ....
       }
   }
   ```

Your contrived example pulls the same values from the same table in two separate queries, so I don't know what your real-world example would be to make it better. Why can;t you just re-use the values pulled from the first query?

Comment: Your suggestions are more tidy up, they won't have any actual effect on the query itself.

Comment: Since the contrived queries are simple I was addressing efficiencies from the C# side instead of the SQL side.

Comment: Creating the connection twice might be a significant slowdown... if so, doing both queries inside the `using` block would potentially speed things up quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample makes no sense. You query two times for the same table. In the first query you get back all the column from the Student table and then you use only the ID and Name fields, in the second one you get back just the student name, but this was already available in the first query

Just one query could be enough (and apply the using statement to properly close and dispose the objects involved)

```
string conString = ".....";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID, Name from Student", con))
{
   con.Open();
   using( SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   while (dr.Read())
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Id is:"+dr[0]+" Name is:"+ dr[1]);
   }
}
```

If you want to execute two queries in the same time, you could append the two queries to the same command separating them with a semicolon

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID, Name from Student;" + 
                                      "Select CourseID, CourseName from Course", con))
```

In this example you get back two set of records, one for the Student table and one for Course table. When you call the ExecuteReader, the readear is positioned on the first result set (the Student list), but you enclose this loop in a do/while block that will control the switch to the second result set (the Course) when the first has been totally read

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    do
    {
        // First time reads the student, when finished, the NextResult call switch the reader
        // on the second set and then exits (because there are no more result sets)
        while(reader.Read())
        {

        }
    }while(reader.NextResult());
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have name in your first query, so why use second query to fetch name.

Few general points :

- Acquire connection as late as possible, and, close them early.
- Re-usable connection instead of opening a new connection every time a connection request to the database is made by the application.
- When you are specifying the connection string, ensure that you specify the IP address of the database server to connect to, 
  rather than the Database Server’s DNS name.

[Credit goes to](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/best-practices-of-adonet.html)

---

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id,Name from Student", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id is:"+dr[0]+" Name is:"+ dr[1]);

            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();  
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
           catch (Exception ex)
          {
           Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
           }
        finally
          {
            if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
             con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Also check this [whether the ADO.NET DataReader or the DataSet is the better tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id is:"+dr[0]+" Name is:"+ dr[1]);
    }
    dr.Close();

    //con.Close();
    //SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
    //con2.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD\Documents\samEE.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name from Student", con);
    //con2.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2;
    dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is :"+ dr2[0]);
    }    
    dr2.Close();

    con.Close();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple queries to a single `SqlCommand` separated by semicolon. Then you can iterate through the data reader like you currently do and at the end request the next query result via `dr.NextResult` method.

Here's a basic code sample

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Something1 FROM Table1;SELECT Something2 FROM Table2" , con)
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

do {
  while (dr.Read())
  {
      // do stuff with results
  }
} while (dr.NextResult())
```

Outer loop iterates thru query results while inner loop goes thru individual rows of current result.

Comment: Actually @Steve is right in your case it should be one query only - to get Name & ID in one go. See his answer.

Comment: i am trying to learn how to make multiple quries .. it was just a practice by the way ...

Comment: @samEE666 Updated my answer to specifically show how use multiple queries with a single command.

Comment: how i am supposed to get result from second query?? plz explain it by code

Comment: @samEE666 when `.NextResult()` is executed - DataReader automatically switches to the second query. So you `while (dr.Read())` begins to read second query